# How to add third-party js and css into AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am a newbie of AngularJS, all right, a newbie of the fronted technology. I want to add third-party js and css resources with my js codes into AngularJS. 
Following is my old html code named `remoteconfig.tpl.html` that works ok which draw some patterns:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/dist/css/next.css">
        <script src="/dist/js/next.js"></script>
        <script src="Data.js"></script>
        <script src="Shell.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
hello world!
    </body>
</html>
```

But i need to move this js and css into angularjs, here is my angularjs module file:

```
define(['angularAMD', 'app/routingConfig', 'app/core/core.services', 'common/config/env.module'], function(ng) {
  var remoteconfigApp = angular.module('app.remoteconfig', ['app.core', 'ui.router.state','config']);

  remoteconfigApp.config(function($stateProvider, $compileProvider, $controllerProvider, $provide, NavHelperProvider, $translateProvider) {
    remoteconfigApp.register = {
      controller : $controllerProvider.register,
      directive : $compileProvider.directive,
      factory : $provide.factory,
      service : $provide.service

    };


    NavHelperProvider.addControllerUrl('app/remoteconfig/remoteconfig.controller');
    NavHelperProvider.addToMenu('remoteconfig', {
     "link" : "#/remoteconfig",
     "active" : "main.remoteconfig",
     "title" : "remoteconfig",
     "icon" : "icon-link",  // Add navigation icon css class here
     "page" : {
        "title" : "remoteconfig",
        "description" : "remoteconfig"
     }
    });

    var access = routingConfig.accessLevels;

    $stateProvider.state('main.remoteconfig', {
        url: 'remoteconfig',
        access: access.admin,
        views : {
            'content' : {
                templateUrl: 'remoteconfig.tpl.html',
                controller: 'remoteconfigCtrl',
                css: 'dist/css/next.css', //include thrid-party css: next.css
                controllerUrl: ['dist/js/next.js', 'Data.js', 'Shell.js'] //include thrid-party js next.css and my js: Data.js and Shell.js
            }
        }
    });

  });

  return remoteconfigApp;
});
```

I add them into the controllerUrl and css option in $stateProvider. And change my new html with just oneline:

```
hello world!
```

The new code can only shows the hello world without patterns. Any suggestions about my problem?

Comment: Have you loaded the angular scripts? Have you added the `ng-app` attribute? Have you included a `<div ui-view></div>`?

Comment: @devqon No, must i change the third-party code and my js code into angular scripts ?

Comment: angular routing doesn't expect you to be loading whole pages inside view containers...just the relevant html for that view